# How can I make YouCompleteMe highlight errors and warnings?

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, youcompleteme

This is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'ldx/vim-indentfinder'
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on
colors zenburn

set encoding=utf-8
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set number

let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1
```

Now, I am trying to use it in a C++ project. The thing is that the compilation errors are not highlighted inside the editor. I know my `.ycm_extra_conf.py` good and well configured, because if run:

```
:YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics
```

and then, in a line I know to be wrong:

```
:YcmShowDetailedDiagnostic
```

I get the expected error message:

```
/home/lvella/src/project/src/main.cpp:56:2: error: unknown type name 'safdsadfsadf'
```

But it is not highlighted. By inspecting `:YcmDiags`, I can see 30 warning messages originated from inside an external library I am using. Now I suspect that error list is filled with up to 30 entries, leaving the ones in my code out of it. Am I right? Can I filter out all the entries not present in the file I am currently looking at? Can I increase the number of entries listed? How to see my errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a matter of reading the manual:

> The g:ycm_max_diagnostics_to_display option
>
> This option controls the maximum number of diagnostics shown to the
>   user when errors or warnings are detected in the file. This option is
>   only relevant if you are using the C-family semantic completion
>   engine.
>
> Default: 30
>
> let g:ycm_max_diagnostics_to_display = 30

I just set this option to 1000 and I could see my error messages.